# "Create Geospatial PDF" makes PDF dimensions much larger

Tags: qgis, geospatial-pdf

I am using QGIS 3.10.9-A.  When I use `Export as PDF...` and check the `Create Geospatial PDF (GeoPDF)` box the size (linear - not number of bytes) of the PDF created is much larger than the desired paper size.  This happens even if the layout is simply a blank sheet of paper.  If I make another PDF without checking the Geospatial PDF option the size is the same as desired paper size.

For example, if I specify the layout to be on Letter-size (11 x 8.5 inches) paper and then open the PDF in Adobe Acrobat, the "Document:" dimensions shown in Acrobat when preparing to print with page scaling set to `None` are 45.8 x 35.4 inches, 4.16 times the paper size.

I can print the PDF on Letter-size paper using page scaling set to `Fit to Printable Area` or `Shrink to Printable Area` (both show a Zoom of 23%) but to print to accurate scale I prefer to set page scaling to `None`.  Also, if combining PDFs of QGIS layouts with PDFs from, say, MS Word, the reader will have to rescale to read.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour for QGIS 3.10.X. Just stumbled upon it, after we produced GeoPDF for months now. Updating to QGIS 3.16 solves this issue, but I still am interested in what could cause this.

Comment: I vaguely remember mention of a bug around GeoPDF sizing or scale on either the dev mailing list or in the issues tracker sometime in the past few months. So this may just be a bug that got fixed. 3.16 will become the LTR in less than 2 weeks, so probably just makes sense to upgrade early or wait (which @Howard_Inoe may already have done).